# Restrict read/write access of new User object to only that user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

It seems no matter what I do the Public role always has read access to User objects. I'm seeing an ACL for Public (Read) and the user (Read/Write).

The below code is supposed to restrict access to the User only. How do I prevent Public from having read access to new User objects?

```
PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:NO];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];

PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username = username;
user.password = password;

[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) { ...
```

Comment: So you don't initially have a current user when you created the ACL?

Comment: Ah good catch, but I'm still wondering why Public always has read access of new User objects despite the fact that my CLP only allows the Create operation?

Comment: The closest thing I've found to an answer is the docs overview of [security edge cases](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-security-edge-cases), but it still makes me uneasy seeing Public with read access.

Comment: I'd generally add an on save cloud code hook for this anyway

Answer (score 1):

When you restrict the public access, your records end up with a private read/write access in User table. Just add the following code in your user `beforeSave` trigger in cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {

    // When creating a new user record
    if(request.object.isNew()) {
        var privateACL = new Parse.ACL();
        privateACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        request.object.setACL(privateACL);

        // other stuff
    }

});
```